# How to fix light leaks on black and white film in Photoshop?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, film, restoration, light-leaks

I have some banding of light leaks on my b/w film. Some are totally white (overexposed), some may be recoverable (hopefully).How can I fix these in Photoshop or Lightroom?

Comment: Care to post any examples of the (hopefully) salvageable images? If the light leaks haven't obliterated the underlying image you can usually do some localised levels adjustment in PS/GIMP to fix it.   Obviously you also want to diagnose the source of the light leak and fix it before shooting another roll.

Comment: Yeah, as said above, there's no way of diagnosing it without seeing the images! If there are totally white bands then it sounds like you're going to have a tough time. Otherwise it's probably just going to be a case of masked levels and a bit of elbow grease!

Comment: Can you redo the scan with decreased light intensity (e.g. using a filter between the light source and the image?)

Answer (score 1):

Unsharp mask option will help to get some details back from the over exposed part ,auto tone ,auto color options may helpful to reduce the blown out 20-30%. Cloning is required if its small patchy leaks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how bad.  You can try to scan it a few times (normal, lighter, and darker) then mask out parts in photoshop.  You can also control shadow and highlight detail in photoshop to improve the areas even more. On the layer you want to bring in more detail go to: Image --> Adjustments --> Shadow/Highlight.  Then under highlights you increase the value to bring out more detail in the blown out parts and the same with darker area you can bring out more shadow detail by increasing the value.  You may also need to do some dodging and burning too.  Once again it all depends on how bad the fogging is, but these steps will greatly improve what you have.

Comment: I'd recommend using a layer(s) set to Overlay and using various luminance from 50% gray to solid black on a brush set to 50/50 opacity/hardness to burn in areas as they need it. The light leak may not be uniform in density, so you'll literally need to brush in sections of burn independently of each other.